# Recursive function counts down 4->0, but then counts up 0>4, how can I stop the count up

Tags: java, recursion, stack

The aim of this code is to confirm the letter A appears 4 times exactly but using a recursive function. I can get it to count correctly, but as soon as it begins to leave the recursive stacks, it then +1 instead of -1 (I think because it is leaving the stack).

Is there a better way to handle this, has me very stuck.

```
    public class App {
    public static boolean isPresentNTimes(String sequence, char marker, int count) {
        System.out.println("This is the count: " + count);
        if (sequence.isEmpty() != true){
            if(sequence.charAt(0) == marker) {
                isPresentNTimes(sequence.substring(1), marker, count-1);
                System.out.println("The count is" + count);
            }
            
            else {
                isPresentNTimes(sequence.substring(1), marker, count);
            }
        }
        
        if (count == 4){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

     public static void main(String []args){
        String seq1 = "ABBAACBA";
        System.out.println(isPresentNTimes(seq1, 'A', 4));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you actually want to implement:

```
public static boolean isPresentNTimes(String sequence, char marker, int count) {
    if(count < 0)
        return false;
    else if(count == 0 && sequence.isEmpty())
        return true;
    else if (!sequence.isEmpty()){
        if(sequence.charAt(0) == marker) {
            System.out.println("The count is " + count );
            count--;
        }
        return isPresentNTimes(sequence.substring(1), marker, count);
    }
    else
       return false;
}
```

Start with `count=4` and decrement every time you found one element equals to mark. Make sure to add return before each recursive call (*i.e.,* return `isPresentNTimes` (...)):

In your code you were comparing

```
  if (count == 4){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

if count == 4, which does not make sense since you start already with count = 4.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will give you the answer ->

```
   static boolean ispresnt(String word, char c, int count) {
    if (word.length() == 0) {
        if (count == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return word.charAt(0) == c ?
            ispresnt(word.substring(1), c, count - 1) : ispresnt(word.substring(1), c, count);
}
```